# Implicit string cast from ShortString to String

Tags: delphi, implicit-conversion

Guys I'm using Delphi XE3, and I'm having this error, I have tried to look at previous questions and tried to solve accordingly but the error wont go away.  Anyone who has used XE3 please help me, am so frustrated.  As still a novice in programming

the [dcc32 Warning] invoice_u.pas(92): W1057 Implicit string cast from 'ShortString' to 'string'

Below is my code

```
procedure TfrmInvoice.btnCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
dmoSales.cdsInvoice.Insert; // insert a new record

dmoSales.cdsInvoice.FieldByName('InvNumber').AsString := invoiceNumber;
dmoSales.cdsInvoice.FieldByName('CustNumber').AsString :=
dmoSales.cdsCustomer.FieldByName('CustNumber').AsString;
dmoSales.cdsInvoice.FieldByName('InvDate').AsDateTime := Date;
dmoSales.cdsInvoice.FieldByName('InvPaid').AsBoolean := chkInvPaid.Checked;

dmoSales.cdsInvoice.Post; // save new record
end;

procedure TfrmInvoice.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
dmoSales.cdsCustomer.Close;
if dmoSales.cdsInvoice.ChangeCount > 0 then
 dmoSales.cdsInvoice.ApplyUpdates(0);
 dmoSales.cdsInvoice.Close;

end;

procedure TfrmInvoice.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
numberOfRecords : integer;
todaysDate : TDateTime;

begin
dmoSales.cdsInvoice.Open;
//get todays date so that the year can be extracted
//add DateUtils to uses clause for YearOf function
todaysDate := Today;
invoiceNumber:= IntToStr(YearOf(todaysDate));
//get the current number of invoices so that it can be added to invoiceNumber
numberOfRecords := dmoSales.cdsInvoice.RecordCount + 1;

//create invoice number
case numberOfRecords  of
1..9:  invoiceNumber := invoiceNumber + '000' + IntToStr(numberOfRecords);
10.99: invoiceNumber := invoiceNumber + '00' + IntToStr(numberOfRecords);
100..999: invoiceNumber := invoiceNumber + '0' + IntToStr(numberOfRecords);
else
     invoiceNumber := invoiceNumber + IntToStr(numberOfRecords);
end;

//display invoice number on form
lblInvNumber.Caption := invoiceNumber;

//get the date and display it on the form
lblDate.Caption := DateToStr(Date);


// get the customers into alphabetic order (using an SQL query)
dmoSales.cdsCustomer.Close; // close the dataset before making changes
dmoSales.sdsCustomer.CommandType := ctQuery; // set dataset up as a query
dmoSales.sdsCustomer.CommandText := 'SELECT*FROM Customer ORDER BY CustName';
dmoSales.cdsCustomer.Open;
dmoSales.cdsCustomer.Refresh;


end;
```

end.

Comment: Given this code, the only possible way I can see that warning occurring is if `invoiceNumber` is a `ShortString` instead of a `String`, in which line 92 would have to be either `dmoSales.cdsInvoice.FieldByName('InvNumber').AsString := invoiceNumber` or `lblInvNumber.Caption := invoiceNumber`.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot tell which line the warning applies to, and we cannot see the types of all the variables in the code. However, the warning message is clear enough. Somewhere you do

```
s := t;
```

where `s` is a `string`, alias for `UnicodeString`, and `t` is a `ShortString`. Since `ShortString` is always ANSI encoded, the compiler is warning you that you are making an implicit conversion from ANSI to UTF-16. It warns you because you ought to be aware of such conversions, and being implicit, it is not immediately obvious from reading the code.

The best way to solve the problem is to stop using the long deprecated `ShortString` type. There's really no place for it today.

If you cannot bring yourself to do that then you may suppress the warning with an explicit conversion.

```
s := string(t);
```

Of course, this provokes the explicit string cast warning [W1059](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/W1059_Explicit_string_cast_from_'%25s'_to_'%25s'_(Delphi)) but that warning is off by default.